# Could not spawn process for application NGINX+ PASSENGER ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, passenger-nginx

Hi I'm using Nginx + Passenger

I'm stuck in the issue.

```
[ E 2020-09-20 09:32:51.5408 14555/To age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/xxxxxxx: A timeout occurred while starting a preloader process.
  Error ID: 55f4b7bd
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-6SSEIC.html

[ E 2020-09-20 09:32:51.5478 14555/T8 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:276 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 55f4b7bd. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

sudo nano /etc/nginx/passenger.conf

```
passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/ruby;
```

Comment: were you able to find solution to this?